# What are binormals used for?

Tags: vector-graphics, normals

I know that the binormal is orthogonal to both the surface normal and tangent in any point on a plane but what are they used for exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of uses, probably much more than can be covered in a simple answer.

One of the most common usage is in shaders. The normal, tangent and binormal can be used to navigate in surface space. They can be used to create a matrix that lets you transform a vector from model space to surface space or texture space. This in turn is used for a lot of different shader effects, e.g. advanced lighting or effects like parallax mapping.